# bash - remove multiple different lines of text from a text file

Tags: macos, bash, text, lines

I'm working with lots of log files, and most log files have lots of repeating strings that are logged multiple times.
To make the logs easily viewable for others who don't have much to do with such things (for myself also), i've wanted to make a script that rips out some text lines that can cause a 'false alarm' to other people. ("Hey admin, i have these errors here multiple times"; > "Sigh, these errors don't mean anything" kind of way)

Is there some bash code with grep, cat or awk that can get rid of **lots of different** text lines, without having to go through the document over and over again for each line to be removed? (basically remove all garbage lines in one swoop)

Example, i'll mark the lines that i want removed in **bold**:

> One thing I don't know why
>
> **It doesn’t even matter how hard you try**
>
> Keep that in mind, I designed this
>   rhyme
>
> To explain in due time
>
> All I know
>
> **time is a valuable thing**
>
> Watch it fly by as the pendulum swings
>
> Watch it count down to the end of the
>   day
>
> **The clock ticks life away**
>
> **It’s so unreal**
>
> Didn’t look out below
>
> Watch the time go right out the window
>
> **Trying to hold on but didn’t even know**
>
> Wasted it all just to
>
> Watch you go

Sorry about the Linkin Park Lyrics, listening to the Radio while trying to solve a problem gives some bad examples sometimes :P

Are all these lines removable in one command?
Many thanks if somebody knows how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep -v "<string1>\|<string2>\|<stringN>" /path/to/file
```

Comment: Thanks. will be useful for making new copies of that log without the garbage in it. 
Shame rep doesn't edit files. Well, there's always temp variables. 

For removing strings on the same file:
grep -v "<string1>\|<string2>\|<stringN>" Logfile.log > $$ && mv $$ Logfile.log

Answer (score 1):

It removes the lines provided in not_wanted array.

```
#!/bin/bash
    exec < example.txt
    not_wanted[0]="It doesn’t even matter how hard you try"
    not_wanted[1]="time is a valuable thing"
    not_wanted[2]="The clock ticks life away"
    not_wanted[3]="It’s so unreal"
    not_wanted[4]="Trying to hold on but didn’t even know"

    while read line; do
        for i in "${not_wanted[@]}"; do
            if [ "$line" == "$i" ]; then unset line; break; fi
        done 
        if [ "$line" ]; then echo "$line"; fi
    done
```

Comment: Also thanks, this is a bit more overseeable than a giant string with grep -v \|

Answer (score 1):

Put the lines you don't want in a file, then

```
grep -v -f not.wanted filename > smaller.file
```