# chunk a text database into N equal blocks and retain header

Tags: python, model, arcgis

I have several large (30+ million lines) text databases which I am cleaning up with the following code, I need to split the file into 1 million lines or less and retain the header line. I have looked at chunk and itertools but can't get a clear solution. It is to use in an arcgis model.

== updated code as per response from icyrock.com

```
import arcpy, os
#fc = arcpy.GetParameter(0)
#chunk_size = arcpy.GetParameter(1) # number of records in each dataset

fc='input.txt'
Name = fc[:fc.rfind('.')]
fl = Name+'_db.txt'

with open(fc) as f:
  lines = f.readlines()
lines[:] = lines[3:]
lines[0] = lines[0].replace('Rx(db)', 'Rx_'+Name)
lines[0] = lines[0].replace('Best Unit', 'Best_Unit')
records = len(lines)
with open(fl, 'w') as f: #where N is the chunk number
  f.write('\n'.join(lines))

with open(fl) as file:
  lines = file.readlines()

headers = lines[0:1]
rest = lines[1:]
chunk_size = 1000000

def chunks(lst, chunk_size):
  for i in xrange(0, len(lst), chunk_size):
    yield lst[i:i + chunk_size]

def write_rows(rows, file):
  for row in rows:
    file.write('%s' % row)

part = 1
for chunk in chunks(rest, chunk_size):
  with open(Name+'_%d' % part+'.txt', 'w') as file:
    write_rows(headers, file)
    write_rows(chunk, file)
  part += 1
```

See [Remove specific lines from a large text file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9473921/remove-specific-lines-from-a-large-text-file-in-python) and [split a large text (xyz) database into x equal parts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612882/split-a-large-text-xyz-database-into-x-equal-parts) for background. I don't want a cygwin based solution any longer as it over complicates the model. I need a pythonic way. We can use the "records" to iterate through but what is not clear is how to specify line 1:999,999 in db #1, lines 1,000,0000 to 1,999,999 in db#2 etc. It's fine if the last dataset has less than 1m records.

Error with 500mb file (I have 16GB RAM).

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "P:\2012\Job_044_DM_Radio_Propogation\Working\test\clean_file.py",
>   line 10, in 
>       lines = f.readlines() MemoryError
>
> > > > records 2249878

The records amount above is not the total record count it just where it went out of memory (I think).

=== With the new code from Icyrock.

The chunk seems to work ok but gives errors when used in Arcgis.

> Start Time: Fri Mar 09 17:20:04 2012 WARNING 000594: Input feature
>   1945882430: falls outside of output geometry domains. WARNING 000595:
>   d:\Temp\cb_vhn007_1.txt_Features1.fid contains the full list of
>   features not able to be copied.

I know it is an issue with chunking as the "Make Event Layer" process works fine with full pre-chunk dataset.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
with open('file') as file:
  lines = file.readlines()

headers = lines[0:1]
rest = lines[1:]
chunk_size = 4

def chunks(lst, chunk_size):
  for i in xrange(0, len(lst), chunk_size):
    yield lst[i:i + chunk_size]

def write_rows(rows, file):
  for row in rows:
    file.write('%s' % row)

part = 1
for chunk in chunks(rest, chunk_size):
  with open('part%d' % part, 'w') as file:
    write_rows(headers, file)
    write_rows(chunk, file)
  part += 1
```

Here's a test run:

```
$ cat file && python mkt.py && for p in part*; do echo ---- $p; cat $p; done
header
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
---- part1
header
1
2
3
4
---- part2
header
5
6
7
8
---- part3
header
9
10
11
12
---- part4
header
13
14
```

Obviously, change the values of the `chunk_size` and how you fetch `headers` depending on their count.

Credits:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/312464/438544

Edit - to do this line-by-line to avoid memory issues, you can do something like this:

```
from itertools import islice

headers_count = 5
chunk_size = 250000

with open('file') as fin:
  headers = list(islice(fin, headers_count))

  part = 1
  while True:
    line_iter = islice(fin, chunk_size)
    try:
      first_line = line_iter.next()
    except StopIteration:
      break
    with open('part%d' % part, 'w') as fout:
      for line in headers:
        fout.write(line)
      fout.write(first_line)
      for line in line_iter:
        fout.write(line)
    part += 1
```

Credits:

- [Python how to read N number of lines at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335839/python-how-to-read-n-number-of-lines-at-a-time)

Test case (put the above in the file called `mkt2.py`):

Make a file containing 5-line header and 1234567 lines in it:

```
with open('file', 'w') as fout:
  for i in range(5):
    fout.write(10 * ('header %d ' % i) + '\n')
  for i in range(1234567):
    fout.write(10 * ('line %d ' % i) + '\n')
```

Shell script to test (put in file called `rt.sh`):

```
rm part*
echo ---- file
head -n7 file
tail -n2 file

python mkt2.py

for i in part*; do
  echo ---- $i
  head -n7 $i
  tail -n2 $i
done
```

Sample output:

```
$ sh rt.sh 
---- file
header 0 header 0 header 0 header 0 header 0 header 0 header 0 header 0 header 0 header 0 
header 1 header 1 header 1 header 1 header 1 header 1 header 1 header 1 header 1 header 1 
header 2 header 2 header 2 header 2 header 2 header 2 header 2 header 2 header 2 header 2 
header 3 header 3 header 3 header 3 header 3 header 3 header 3 header 3 header 3 header 3 
header 4 header 4 header 4 header 4 header 4 header 4 header 4 header 4 header 4 header 4 
line 0 line 0 line 0 line 0 line 0 line 0 line 0 line 0 line 0 line 0 
line 1 line 1 line 1 line 1 line 1 line 1 line 1 line 1 line 1 line 1 
line 1234565 line 1234565 line 1234565 line 1234565 line 1234565 line 1234565 line 1234565 line 1234565 line 1234565 line 1234565 
line 1234566 line 1234566 line 1234566 line 1234566 line 1234566 line 1234566 line 1234566 line 1234566 line 1234566 line 1234566 
---- part1
header 0 header 0 header 0 header 0 header 0 header 0 header 0 header 0 header 0 header 0 
header 1 header 1 header 1 header 1 header 1 header 1 header 1 header 1 header 1 header 1 
header 2 header 2 header 2 header 2 header 2 header 2 header 2 header 2 header 2 header 2 
header 3 header 3 header 3 header 3 header 3 header 3 header 3 header 3 header 3 header 3 
header 4 header 4 header 4 header 4 header 4 header 4 header 4 header 4 header 4 header 4 
line 0 line 0 line 0 line 0 line 0 line 0 line 0 line 0 line 0 line 0 
line 1 line 1 line 1 line 1 line 1 line 1 line 1 line 1 line 1 line 1 
line 249998 line 249998 line 249998 line 249998 line 249998 line 249998 line 249998 line 249998 line 249998 line 249998 
line 249999 line 249999 line 249999 line 249999 line 249999 line 249999 line 249999 line 249999 line 249999 line 249999 
---- part2
header 0 header 0 header 0 header 0 header 0 header 0 header 0 header 0 header 0 header 0 
header 1 header 1 header 1 header 1 header 1 header 1 header 1 header 1 header 1 header 1 
header 2 header 2 header 2 header 2 header 2 header 2 header 2 header 2 header 2 header 2 
header 3 header 3 header 3 header 3 header 3 header 3 header 3 header 3 header 3 header 3 
header 4 header 4 header 4 header 4 header 4 header 4 header 4 header 4 header 4 header 4 
line 250000 line 250000 line 250000 line 250000 line 250000 line 250000 line 250000 line 250000 line 250000 line 250000 
line 250001 line 250001 line 250001 line 250001 line 250001 line 250001 line 250001 line 250001 line 250001 line 250001 
line 499998 line 499998 line 499998 line 499998 line 499998 line 499998 line 499998 line 499998 line 499998 line 499998 
line 499999 line 499999 line 499999 line 499999 line 499999 line 499999 line 499999 line 499999 line 499999 line 499999 
---- part3
header 0 header 0 header 0 header 0 header 0 header 0 header 0 header 0 header 0 header 0 
header 1 header 1 header 1 header 1 header 1 header 1 header 1 header 1 header 1 header 1 
header 2 header 2 header 2 header 2 header 2 header 2 header 2 header 2 header 2 header 2 
header 3 header 3 header 3 header 3 header 3 header 3 header 3 header 3 header 3 header 3 
header 4 header 4 header 4 header 4 header 4 header 4 header 4 header 4 header 4 header 4 
line 500000 line 500000 line 500000 line 500000 line 500000 line 500000 line 500000 line 500000 line 500000 line 500000 
line 500001 line 500001 line 500001 line 500001 line 500001 line 500001 line 500001 line 500001 line 500001 line 500001 
line 749998 line 749998 line 749998 line 749998 line 749998 line 749998 line 749998 line 749998 line 749998 line 749998 
line 749999 line 749999 line 749999 line 749999 line 749999 line 749999 line 749999 line 749999 line 749999 line 749999 
---- part4
header 0 header 0 header 0 header 0 header 0 header 0 header 0 header 0 header 0 header 0 
header 1 header 1 header 1 header 1 header 1 header 1 header 1 header 1 header 1 header 1 
header 2 header 2 header 2 header 2 header 2 header 2 header 2 header 2 header 2 header 2 
header 3 header 3 header 3 header 3 header 3 header 3 header 3 header 3 header 3 header 3 
header 4 header 4 header 4 header 4 header 4 header 4 header 4 header 4 header 4 header 4 
line 750000 line 750000 line 750000 line 750000 line 750000 line 750000 line 750000 line 750000 line 750000 line 750000 
line 750001 line 750001 line 750001 line 750001 line 750001 line 750001 line 750001 line 750001 line 750001 line 750001 
line 999998 line 999998 line 999998 line 999998 line 999998 line 999998 line 999998 line 999998 line 999998 line 999998 
line 999999 line 999999 line 999999 line 999999 line 999999 line 999999 line 999999 line 999999 line 999999 line 999999 
---- part5
header 0 header 0 header 0 header 0 header 0 header 0 header 0 header 0 header 0 header 0 
header 1 header 1 header 1 header 1 header 1 header 1 header 1 header 1 header 1 header 1 
header 2 header 2 header 2 header 2 header 2 header 2 header 2 header 2 header 2 header 2 
header 3 header 3 header 3 header 3 header 3 header 3 header 3 header 3 header 3 header 3 
header 4 header 4 header 4 header 4 header 4 header 4 header 4 header 4 header 4 header 4 
line 1000000 line 1000000 line 1000000 line 1000000 line 1000000 line 1000000 line 1000000 line 1000000 line 1000000 line 1000000 
line 1000001 line 1000001 line 1000001 line 1000001 line 1000001 line 1000001 line 1000001 line 1000001 line 1000001 line 1000001 
line 1234565 line 1234565 line 1234565 line 1234565 line 1234565 line 1234565 line 1234565 line 1234565 line 1234565 line 1234565 
line 1234566 line 1234566 line 1234566 line 1234566 line 1234566 line 1234566 line 1234566 line 1234566 line 1234566 line 1234566
```

Timing of the above:

```
real    0m0.935s
user    0m0.708s
sys     0m0.200s
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but due to the size I get a memory error. See updated question. Can we modify the "rest =" line to be - lines[1:1000000] on run 1 then lines[10000001:2000000] etc?

Comment: See the edit for the version that works line-by-line, so avoids the memory problem on large files. It takes less then a second for 1+ million line file breaking into 250k line parts, so should work quite well for your case.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work fine but then when I try to process it in arcgis I get an error. I know that it's something to do with the "Chunking" as the copy process works ok on the full file, before the chunk. I needed the chunk as other processes didn't work due to the size. See update to question.

Comment: Sorry, not familiar with arcgis. Is it possible that lines are related? E.g. if you try copying a header and 10 random lines from your file, will that work in general? If not, then chunking will fail.